# Find the minimum of a function containing the norm of another function

Tags: optimization, maxima-minima, jacobian

This is my first post here, I've been struggling with a problem for maths course, and would appreciate any guidelines on how to start tackling it (not asking for the answer, just some guidelines on how to begin).

$$
\min_{\mathbf{x}} \phi(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2} ||g(\mathbf{x}) - b||^2
$$

And they also tell me that the Jacobian of $g(\mathbf{x}) = A$. There's no other additional information, so I'm assuming that the domains and codomains are $\mathbb{R}^n$

Really would appreciate any tips on how to begin!

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. Your question is much too vague for an answer, even for a tip. If you [edit] to give us some context we may be able to help. What are the domains and codomains of these functions? What hypotheses do they satisfy? What course is this for? What  have you tried?

Comment: Hi Ethan, thanks for the guidelines, unfortunately the only information I have is the one provided. This is part of the optimization section of a course named advanced topics in mathematics for engineering.

Comment: Without more data this is unanswerable. Look back in the book and tell us exactly what kinds of things $x$, $g$, $b$ and $\phi$ are. How does $A$ fit into the picture since it's nowhere in the equation you ask about? Do you really understand everything in the book up to this equation? If not, then you should ask about earlier material. Left as is the question will be closed.